# PyQt5 Button dont work when I import it, but works when main

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I use PyQt5 Designer to create two windows. My idea is to change first(main) window when I press button and this works fine. So now I have second window that has other button with function to show hidden label. But when I press that button nothing happens. When I open second window as main, button works perfectly. Here is my first window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from SecondWindow import *


class Ui_FirstWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):
        FirstWindow.setObjectName("FirstWindow")
        FirstWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_ChangeWindow = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_ChangeWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 330, 281, 91))
        self.pushButton_ChangeWindow.setObjectName("pushButton_ChangeWindow")
        self.pushButton_ChangeWindow.clicked.connect(self.change_window)   # Link button with funcion
        FirstWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(FirstWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FirstWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FirstWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FirstWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FirstWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_ChangeWindow.setText(_translate("FirstWindow", "Change Window"))

    def change_window(self):
        ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
        ui.setupUi(FirstWindow)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FirstWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_FirstWindow()
    ui.setupUi(FirstWindow)
    FirstWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here everything works fine. When I click button it shows me second window. Code for second window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_ShowLabel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_ShowLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 260, 241, 81))
        self.pushButton_ShowLabel.setObjectName("pushButton_ShowLabel")
        self.pushButton_ShowLabel.clicked.connect(self.show_hidden_label)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 130, 121, 51))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        # Hide label
        self.label.hide()
        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    

        self.retranslateUi(SecondWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, SecondWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SecondWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("SecondWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_ShowLabel.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Show Label"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Hello"))

    def show_hidden_label(self):
        self.label.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    SecondWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
    ui.setupUi(SecondWindow)
    SecondWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now I click button on new window but it does nothing. When I start this code as main, everything works fine.

I started coding about 1 month ago so sorry if code is confusing or something. I appriciate any help and advice

Comment: The issue is that the `ui` created in 'change_window` is a local variable that gets destroyed when the function returns: since `show_hidden_label` is also part of that object, it's destroyed along with it. You could change to `self.second = Ui_SecondWindow()`, but that won't solve other two important issues: 1. pyuic files should **never** be edited (as explained in their headers), and you should follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html); 2. you should never call `setupUi()` more than once on the same widget.

Comment: If you want a "multi page" interface, use [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) and add individual "pages" (widgets) to it. Note that you should only add standard/container widgets in QStackedWidget, not widgets that are intended as *top level windows* (like QMainWindow and especially QDialog). Create new "Widgets" in Designer, copy the existing contents of your main windows into them, and use those instead.